# T-sql :get SUM of Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a table that looks something like the following :

```
          W1  W2 w3
Gold      10    2    3              
Silver     3    1    1
```

but i need a result :

```
          W1  W2  w3
Gold      10  12  15            
Silver     3  4  5
```

Is there any way i can get that result?

My sql query :

```
SELECT  
   week1=[1],week2=[2],week3=[3]
FROM
(
    SELECT
    [week]=DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,ta.enddate),ta.id
    FROM
    table1 ta where ta.enddate BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(id) FOR week IN ( 
        [1],[2],[3])
) piv
```

Comment: In Reporting Services you can use the running value function to do the test you want

Comment: Hi fabio ,yes thats what i want , but it's not working for me .

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.??, t.w1, (t.w1 + t.w2) as w2, (t.w1 + t.w2 + t.w3) as w3
from table1 t;
```

I don't know what the name of the first column is, so I just used `??`.

Answer (score 0):

One thought, since you tagged this question with Reporting Services.  If, in the end, you are displaying the info using Reporting Services I would highly consider using the Matrix tool to do the pivoting and summation of the data because that is exactly what it does.

To further explain as it seems you are going to use SSRS.  Your matrix would have a dataset that would be similar to this:

```
SELECT
   [week]=DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,ta.enddate),
   ta.id,
   ta.MetalType as GoldorSilver
FROM  table1 ta 
where ta.enddate BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
```

The matrix would have a header and footer and column group would be [Week] with a Column Group total to do the sum across the week.  The row group footer would do the sum across all weeks.

Comment: Hello Jesse ,but i can use summation for the entire row (all weeks),not just the week i'am positioned at?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes.  You would have the dataset for the matrix just list weeks and medal counts per person then have the matrix have a group header and footer.  The footer would do all weeks and the column group sum would do the sum across the week.

Comment: But the sum i would have is just across the week , or across all weeks.instead i want to have if the column is week1 (sum week1),if the column is week2(sum (week1+week2)) and my columns are not dynamics .

Comment: Both.  One is a column group summary (across the week) and one is a row group summary (across all weeks).

Comment: Here is a good video to watch on how to use the Matrix object.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zERexbgCG5A

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the running total before pivoting the data

```
SELECT element, 
       week1=[1],week2=[2],week3=[3]
FROM
(
SELECT [week] = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,ta.enddate),
       price = sum(ta.price)Over(Partition by element Order by enddate),
       element  
FROM table1 ta 
where ta.enddate BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
) src
PIVOT
(
 SUM(price) FOR week IN ( [1],[2],[3])
) piv
```

for older versions

```
SELECT element, 
       week1=[1],week2=[2],week3=[3]
FROM
(
SELECT [week] = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,ta.enddate),
       cs.price,
       element  
FROM table1 ta 
cross apply(select sum(price) from table1 tb 
            where ta.element = tb.element and ta.enddate >= tb.enddate ) cs (price)
where ta.enddate BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
) src
PIVOT
(
 SUM(price) FOR week IN ( [1],[2],[3])
) piv
```