# Total running on dynamics columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that looks something like the following :

```
          W1  W2 w3
Gold      10    2    3              
Silver     3    1    1
```

but i need a result :

```
          W1  W2  w3
Gold      10  12  15            
Silver     3  4  5
```

Is there any way i can get that result?

My sql query :

```
SELECT  
   week1=[1],week2=[2],week3=[3]
FROM
(
    SELECT
    [week]=DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,ta.enddate),ta.price
    FROM
    table1 ta where ta.enddate BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(price) FOR week IN ( 
        [1],[2],[3])
) piv
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928558/t-sql-get-sum-of-columns

Comment: Is this about MySQL or SQL Server? It can't be both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the running total before pivoting the data

```
SELECT element, 
       week1=[1],week2=[2],week3=[3]
FROM
(
SELECT [week] = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,ta.enddate),
       price = sum(ta.price)Over(Partition by element Order by enddate),
       element  
FROM table1 ta 
where ta.enddate BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
) src
PIVOT
(
 SUM(price) FOR week IN ( [1],[2],[3])
) piv
```

for older versions

```
SELECT element, 
       week1=[1],week2=[2],week3=[3]
FROM
(
SELECT [week] = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,ta.enddate),
       cs.price,
       element  
FROM table1 ta 
cross apply(select sum(price) from table1 tb 
            where ta.element = tb.element and ta.enddate >= tb.enddate ) cs (price)
where ta.enddate BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
) src
PIVOT
(
 SUM(price) FOR week IN ( [1],[2],[3])
) piv
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it's working